# Install Numpy on Mac for Python 3 while Numpy for Python2.7 is already installed

Tags: macos, python-3.x, numpy

I have installed both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 on Mac.
Also Before installing 3.4, I have installed Numpy on python 2.7.
However, when I run python 3.4 it says that there's no numpy.
Meaning that I can only use numpy on python 2.7.
How can I install numpy on Python 3.4???

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you use `pip` to install `numpy`?  `pip` is for Python 2.  You need to use `pip3` for Python 3: `pip3 install numpy`.

Comment: Oh that works! Thank you!

Comment: Please, get used to creating virtual environments and by doing so specifying the Python version when creating them if possible. This way you would avoid these kind of "issues".